# Custom post type capability type 'page' not working

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to create a custom post type that's supposed to be used for a publication issue -> article structure. Since the hierarchical structure is [really only meant for pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) (refer to `hierarchical` section's note), I figured I'd configure the custom post type to act as a page.

Great, except I can't get it to work properly. Even after setting `capability_type` to `page` and `hierarchical` to `true`, the edit screen for the post type is still acting as though it's a post. There aren't any "parent" or "page template" attribute drop down menus.

If I change the `capability_type` from `page` to `post`, literally nothing changes with the edit screen.

Here's my code:

```
register_post_type('publication', array(
    'label' => 'Publication',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'publication', 'with_front' => true),
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','comments','revisions','author','page-attributes'),
    'labels' => array (
        'name' => 'Publications',
        'singular_name' => 'Publication',
        'menu_name' => 'Publications',
    )
));
```

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: First of all... `Capability_type` has nothing to do with this. It's used to construct permissions. Do you have any plugins enabled on this site?

Answer (score 2):

I've taken this from another site I have made which uses the hierarchical structure and it works. (I have amended to fit your post type)

```
function register_publications_cpt() {

        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Publications', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Publication', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', ''),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Publication'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Publication'),
            'new_item' => __('New Publication'),
            'all_items' => __('All Publication'),
            'view_item' => __('View Publication'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Publications'),
            'not_found' =>  __('No Publications found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Publications found in Trash'), 
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => 'Publications'
        );

        $args = array(
            'hierarchical' => true,     
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true, 
            'show_in_menu' => true, 
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'page',
            'has_archive' => false, 
            'menu_position' => 22,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'page-attributes', 'custom-fields' )
        ); 

        register_post_type('publication', $args);

}
add_action('init', 'register_publications_cpt');
```

Comment: Still no luck. I thought this was strange because I've too done this exact thing before, but yet on this site, it's not working. Would there be any site configuration option that could be messing this up?

Comment: Have you done the usual, disable all plugins and switch to a default theme i.e twentythirteen?

Comment: Yes. No plugins, Twentythirteen theme (with CPT code added to functions.php), still not working. Strange...

Comment: Can you see my amended answer and see if that works?

Comment: Nothing :/ I've even tried using the Custom Post Type UI addon and that doesn't work either.

Comment: The code is correct, it's the same that I've used on other sites and it works just fine. It must be some configuration option that's messing it up...

Comment: Sounds like your WP install is broken, try reinstalling/reuploading files.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I was looking for the answer myself...

You need two things here when creating your post type to fix this:

```
'hierarchical' => true,
'supports' => array('page-attributes'),
```

That will give you a template select and an order menu.